# How to backup a database by pyodbc

Tags: python, database, backup, pyodbc

The backup statement can't be used in a transaction when it execute with pyodbc cursor. It seems that the pyodbc execute the query inside a default transaction. 
I have also tried to use the autocommit mode or add the commit statement before the backup statement. Both of these are not working.

```
#can't execute the backup statement in transaction
cur.execute("backup database database_name to disk = 'backup_path'")
#not working too
cur.execute("commit;backup database database_name to disk = 'backup_path'")
```

Is it possible to execute the backup statement by pyodbc? Thanks in advance!

-----Added aditional info-----------------------------------------------------------------------

The backup operation is encapsulate in a function such as:

```
def backupdb(con, name, save_path):
    # with autocommit mode, should be pyodbc.connect(con, autocommit=True)
    con = pyodbc.connect(con) 
    query = "backup database %s to disk = '%s'" % (name, save_path)
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute(query)
    cur.commit()
    con.close()
```

If the function is called by following code,

```
backupdb('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=.\sqlexpress;DATABASE=master;Trusted_Connection=yes',
             'DatabaseName',
             'd:\\DatabaseName.bak')
```

then the exception will be:

```
File "C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop/bakdb.py", line 14, in <module>'d:\\DatabaseName.bak')
File "C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop/bakdb.py", line 7, in backupdb cur.execute(query)
ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot perform a backup or restore operation within a transaction. (3021) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally. (3013)')
```

With open the keyword autocommit=True, the function will run silently but there is no backup file generated in the backup folder.

Comment: Have you tired `cur.autocommit = True` before executing backup? Also give more info about database and show us error message.

Comment: @MichałNiklas, The aditional info is added, thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming you are using SQL Server, specify `autocommit=True` when the connection is built:

```
>>> import pyodbc
>>> connection = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}', 
                                server='InstanceName', database='master', 
                                trusted_connection='yes', autocommit=True)
>>> backup = "BACKUP DATABASE [AdventureWorks] TO DISK = N'AdventureWorks.bak'"
>>> cursor = connection.cursor().execute(backup)
>>> connection.close()
```

This is using `pyodbc 3.0.7` with `Python 3.3.2`. I believe with older versions of pyodbc you needed to use [Cursor.nextset()](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#nextset) for the backup file to be created. For example:

```
>>> import pyodbc
>>> connection = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}', 
                                server='InstanceName', database='master', 
                                trusted_connection='yes', autocommit=True)
>>> backup = "E:\AdventureWorks.bak"
>>> sql = "BACKUP DATABASE [AdventureWorks] TO DISK = N'{0}'".format(backup)
>>> cursor = connection.cursor().execute(sql)
>>> while cursor.nextset():
>>>    pass
>>> connection.close()
```

It's worth noting that I didn't have to use Cursor.nextset() for the backup file to be created with the current version of pyodbc and SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: The pyodbc version is pyodbc-3.0.7.win32-py2.7 and python environment is py2.7, I'm running on the backup script in XP with SQL Express 2005. Your first code snippets will trigger exception as I mention in the question. I will try the second.

Comment: @Erxin Please edit your question with the actual exception text that is logged

Comment: The exception detail and the code snippets is added. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: @Erxin You're not using `autocommit=True` in the samples posted. Add this to the connection instantiation and it will work.

Comment: Your second code snippet is work! I don't know why the first one doesn't work. I wrote as the same logic as the first code snippet before ask the question. Thanks for your helps!

Comment: @Erxin Please accept the answer if it helped solve your problem. Glad it's working!

Comment: How could you find the documents about the pyodbc, the doc on the google code is not sufficient. Is there any other versions of the doc about the lib pyodbc? Thanks again!

Comment: For me, when not using the `while cursor.nextset(): pass` piece, my backup would run but no failure would be reported and no backup file would persist. Those lines made it work. Similar to this issue: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/471

Answer (score 1):

After hours I found solution. It must be performed no MASTER, other sessions must be terminated, DB must be set to OFFLINE, then RESTORE and then set to ONLINE again.

```
def backup_and_restore():
server = 'localhost,1433'
database = 'myDB'
username = 'SA'
password = 'password'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE=MASTER;UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cnxn.autocommit = True

def execute(cmd):
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(cmd)
    while cursor.nextset():
        pass
    cursor.close()

execute("BACKUP DATABASE [myDB] TO DISK = N'/usr/src/app/myDB.bak'")
# do something .......
execute("ALTER DATABASE [myDB] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;")
execute("ALTER DATABASE [myDB] SET OFFLINE;")
execute("RESTORE DATABASE [myDB] FROM DISK = N'/usr/src/app/myDB.bak' WITH REPLACE")
execute("ALTER DATABASE [myDB] SET ONLINE;")
execute("ALTER DATABASE [myDB] SET MULTI_USER;")
```

Comment: Why are you apparently restoring the database right after you back it up?

Comment: We need somehow run the high level tests on real DB (each test should be independent, so the database should be "the same" for each test). Other option are welcome :-)