# Error: "Cannot perform a backup or restore operation within a transaction." when trying to backup MSSQL database using pyodbc and freetds

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc, freetds

I'm currently running into some problems when I'm trying to backup a MSSQL database from a Linux host using pyodbc and freetds. The versions are as follows:

Python 2.7.6, pyodbc 3.0.7, freetds 0.91-2, Centos 6.5

The code I'm running are as follows (with names and passwords etc removed):

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=FreeTDS;SERVER=<servername>;PORT=<port>;DATABASE=<database>;UID=<user>;PWD=<password>;TDS_Version=8.0;Autocommit=True;')
sql = "exec dbo.backupStashDB"
cursor=conn.cursor().execute(sql)
while cursor.nextset():
   pass
conn.close()
```

The error message I get is:

```
exec dbo.backupnameDB
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "soph_stash_db_bkp.py", line 6, in <module>
conn.execute(sql)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Cannot perform a backup or restore operation within a transaction. (3021) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

I get the same message whether or not I run the command 'manually' or via a stored procedure as in this code example.

I did some googling and found references to adding 'Autocommit=True' would resolve this problem but that doesn't seem to make any difference at all.

Does anyone have any helpful insights to share on this one?

Thanks in advance, Mike

Comment: `DATABASE=<database>` are you using the Target Database name or `Master` ?? It should be `Master`.

Comment: @M.Ali

Thanks for your reply. I'm not sure if I follow you, but I swapped the database name for Master in the connect string and I get the following error instead.

`pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.backupStashDB'. (2812) (SQLExecDirectW)"`

Did I misunderstand your reply or is this the stored procedure 'in the wrong place'?

Comment: @SwedishMike The stored procedure error you received is due to the stored procedure not existing in `master`. The original error you received isn't caused by invalid database context. Pick back up with your original code and take a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067012/how-to-backup-a-database-by-pyodbc/20073322#20073322) to a similar question.

Comment: @beargle Many thanks for your reply as well.

I had a look at your reply and what I see you recommend is to have the `autocommit=True` portion in there or am I missing something else?

If that is it, I do have that bit in my code and I still get the transaction error?

Comment: One other comment, although this isn't the cause; you actually want to use "TDS_Version=7.2;" in your connection string, per http://www.freetds.org/userguide/choosingtdsprotocol.htm

Comment: @FlipperPA Cheers! Have updated that, cut and paste without knowing what I'm doing is the reason behind that. ;)

At least that is correct now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`autocommit` should be specified as a keyword argument to the [pyodbc.connect](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Module#connect) function, it is not part of the ODBC connection string. See the section that starts with:

"*Some keywords are used by pyodbc and are not passed to the odbc driver...*"

---

Modify your code to the following:

```
...
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=FreeTDS;SERVER=<servername>;PORT=<port>;DATABASE=<database>;UID=<user>;PWD=<password>;TDS_Version=8.0;',
                      autocommit=True)
...
```

Comment: Many thanks for that - that explained, and solved, it all. You are a star!